# Funny string python solution

Tags: python, programming-challenge, functional-programming

Problem Statement

> Suppose you have a string \$S\$ which has length \$N\$ and is indexed from \$0\$ to \$N−1\$. String \$R\$ is the reverse of the string \$S\$. The string \$S\$ is funny if the condition \$|S_i−S_{i−1}|=|R_i−R_{i−1}|\$ is true for every \$i\$ from \$1\$ to \$N−1\$.
>
> (Note: Given a string \$str\$, \$str_i\$ denotes the ascii value of the \$i\$th character (0-indexed) of \$str\$. \$|x|\$ denotes the absolute value of an integer \$x\$)

Example

`is_funny("acxz")` returns `True`

`is_funny("bcxz")` returns `False`

Solution

```
def is_palindrome(ary):
    return ary == ary[::-1]

def create_difference_list(s):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        res.append(abs(ord(s[i]) - ord(s[i-1])))
    return res

def is_happystr(s):
    return is_palindrome(create_difference_list(s))
```

Notes

- Have used slow version of palindrome check assuming string is not going to be too long. Hope it doesn't affect performance that much.
- Approached problem via functional style, could have done all the computation in the same loop but is it a good practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your specific questions:

> Have used slow version of palindrome check assuming string is not going to be too long. Hope it doesn't affect performance that much.

You made a very good choice. This solution is simpler and more readable, you may switch to a new faster implementation later iff performance becomes a problem and you are sure `is_palindrome` is the problem.

> Approached problem via functional style, could have done all the computation in the same loop but is it a good practice?

To be precise on terminology, you used an imperative style with subroutines. I think that the use of subroutines ("functions") like you do greatly improves readability, so well done.

---

You may re-factor into functions further by writing a function to return pairs from a list and calling it from `create_difference_list`

Comment: Hmm, but if we just look at the `is_happystr` then its seems functional style isn't it? provided we don't mutate the original data in between. Also, I find that while problem solving it helps a lot to divide the problem in small pieces like this. Instead of writing whole logic in one place.

Comment: So, overall its a good programming style as I infer from your answer. But there is a problem I asked where I was needed to calculate the sum of even `fibonacci` terms, there I was strongly criticized for using a separate `fib` function which returned the `nth` fib term. I was instead asked to have an iterative solution with sum calculation part inline.

Comment: I can give you that link if you want.

Comment: Here it is [Even fibonacci numbers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104775/project-euler-2-even-fibonacci-numbers), even you have gave your version of solution there. But I was strongly criticized by others.

Comment: @CodeYogi criticized because in that case the function was not needed and just added complexity

Comment: So, how do we or you decide when a function is needed or just a overkill? I think the rational there was the caching overhead and all, right?

Answer (score 3):

You could create the result of `create_difference` in one line with a list comprehension, that way you can return it directly. A list comprehension collapses a `for` loop into one line, here's how it'd look:

```
def create_difference_list(s):
    return [abs(ord(s[i]) - ord(s[i-1])) for i in range(1, len(s))]
```

Comment: I don't go for one liners. I would instead create a `summary variable` like `abs_diff` which can let the reader know what's going on. wdyt?

Comment: @CodeYogi I think if you're concerned with informing the user then a docstring is more useful. `abs_diff` isn't entirely clear by itself, while a sentence in a docstring could tell the user about the function in a clear way.

Answer (score 1):

`create_difference_list` sounds weird to me; `difference_list` sounds nicer. We don't have `create_reversed` or `create_enumerate`, after all.

Anything of the form

```
foo = []
for elem in elems:
    foo.append(func(elem))
```

is more neatly expressible as

```
foo = [func(elem) for elem in elems)]
```

given it's of reasonable length, so in this case I would use

```
def difference_list(s):
    return [abs(ord(s[i]) - ord(s[i-1])) for i in range(1, len(s))]
```

as SuperBiasedMan suggests.

However, [there is a standard recipe for pairwise iteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

which you should use, since it's standard.

Comment: Agree but not completely, if every line of your code requires your reader to lookup documentation then it defies the concept of readability all together, trickery should be limited to [Code Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).